# SQL Sub Query to find duplicates

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am trying to create a query to find duplicates in a table.  Then I want to know details about the duplicates.  I think I need to use a sub-query for this but I'm having a hard time understanding what I need to do.

For example, this query produces my duplicates:

```
SELECT [BINLOCATION], COUNT(*) as counted
FROM [MAS_RDP].[dbo].[IM_ITEMWAREHOUSE]
where QUANTITYONHAND > '0' 
group by BINLOCATION
having COUNT(*) > '1'
```

Know I want to know the details of those results.

IE:

```
SELECT ITEMCODE, BINLOCATION 
FROM IM_ITEMWAREHOUSE where BINLOCATION = (
  SELECT [BINLOCATION], COUNT(*) as counted
  FROM [MAS_RDP].[dbo].[IM_ITEMWAREHOUSE]
  where QUANTITYONHAND > '0'
  group by BINLOCATION
  having COUNT(*) > '1')
```

But that produces the result:
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `COUNT(*)` from the select list and change `BINLOCATION = (...` to `BINLOCATION IN (...`

```
SELECT ITEMCODE, BINLOCATION 
FROM IM_ITEMWAREHOUSE where BINLOCATION IN (
  SELECT [BINLOCATION]
  FROM [MAS_RDP].[dbo].[IM_ITEMWAREHOUSE]
  where QUANTITYONHAND > '0'
  group by BINLOCATION
  having COUNT(*) > '1')
```

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do this query -- in most databases -- is to use the `count(*)` window function:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT iw.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by binlocation) as cnt
      FROM [MAS_RDP].[dbo].[IM_ITEMWAREHOUSE]
      where QUANTITYONHAND > '0'
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return two columns in your subquery to do the comparison in the WHERE clause. As a solution you can concatenate ITEMCODE and BINLOCATION like ITEMCODE-BINLOCATION with sql code.